# Do we want this question about how to handle an unsatisfied project manager?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, migration

There's a question on the Workplace SE that I was thinking about having moved to Project Management SE.

It seems like it would be more on topic here in it's current form, assuming we can address the project management aspects of the problem.

What do you think?

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15433/how-to-handle-unsatisfied-project-manager

Comment: Sure. Send it over.

Comment: I downvoted the question as a disagreement vote, rather than as an indication that the post was poorly written. I hate this aspect of meta discussions, but see [this downvote magnet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135384/185951) for the community's defense of "meta votes are different."

Comment: Also see a [related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126590/185951) that got 34 upvotes for positing the same underlying question. How crazy is that? `<rant>Meta is a bad mechanism for discussions.</rant>`

Comment: @CodeGnome - There's no danger of that happening here. I think that problem only exists on MSO. So please, downvote if you disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

This question belongs on Workplace, not PMSE. The things that make it *sound* like a PMSE question are red herrings, and not really the central point of the original question.

### Not a Project Management Question

The question is not about either the project management profession or about project management frameworks/methodologies. This is strictly an office-politics issue.

The OP isn't dealing with facts, he's dealing with *feelings*. Specifically, he's framing it with:

> [T]his kind of behavior is making us more frustrated and making our employees' efforts useless.

His real questions are all about "managing up" and addressing a political situation from a staffer's point of view. He sums it all up with:

> Can anybody tell me how to convince him respectfully? If it is a common behavior, then tell us how to overcome this kind of situation?

Because of the subjective nature of these two questions, answers will be:

1. Opinion-based anecdotes.
2. A response to an opinion-poll.
3. Too broad in scope.
4. Possibly not applicable to anyone but the OP or the answerer.

### It Would Be Just as Closeable Here

If the question were migrated here without heavy editing, I'd have to vote to close. It was already closed as "Too Broad" on Workplace, rather than as "Off-Topic," and I don't see how migrating it here would make the question inherently any narrower.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the question is valid @ PM.SE, as long as the OP wants to have an answer for his question from a PM perspective. Otherwise he'll be reluctant / defensive to hear our thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the asker [didn't intend for the post to be about project management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15433/how-to-handle-a-project-manager-who-is-not-getting-satisfied-with-his-own-design#comment38802_15433):

> @jmort253 As i am a non-native English speaker, I could not able to write the question with cent percent precision. Thanks for updating the same. You can see my above comment for Neuromancer to know about the nature of the question. I really did not ask anything about Project management. Again Thanks. – Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

I guess it is truly best to focus only on questions closed as off-topic and not for other reasons. Thanks for participating in the discussion everyone; I apologize for the distraction.